Calculating prediction confidence from a sequence of token-level confidences
I am working with OCSR (optical chemical structure recognition) models, and they output a sequence of token-level confidences. I am looking for a method of summarising these token-level confidences into a confidence of the entire prediction. My question is therefore, are there any standards for how this is typically done?
My current thoughts are some sort of mean, although the choice of what mean i.e. arithmetic or geometric mean can potentially significantly change the results. There is also the possibility of just computing the product of all of the confidences, although from my tests this seems to greatly underestimate the model's measured performance.
